Angular - Bootstrap 5 Carousel is not working
I'm trying to use Bootstrap Carousel in Angular (17). The Previous & Next buttons are not working. The carousel remains stuck in the first image. No errors in the console. I see a lot of questions posted here with the same problem, but none of them with an answer (that works).
I have copied/pasted the following HTML (in a component called goals.component.html) from the Bootstrap website and added some random pictures from the web:
<div class="bd-example">
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://abeltasmanmuseum.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/Foto-Borg-Rikkerda.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://abeltasmanmuseum.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://abeltasmanmuseum.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

The Typescript file is as follows (didn't change anything there, just a default Angular TS file):
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-goals',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './goals.component.html',
  styleUrl: './goals.component.css'
})
export class GoalsComponent {

}

In the angular.json file, I have added the Bootstrap reference to both scripts and styles:
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]

Does anyone have an idea what else is missing?
Many thanks!!

From Bootstrap Carousel docs,

Control and indicator elements must have a data-bs-target attribute (or href for links) that matches the id of the .carousel element.

From your code, you are using the data-* attribute which was only available before Bootstrap version 5. According to the Migration docs,

Data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to help distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your own code. For example, we use data-bs-toggle instead of data-toggle.

Migrate all the data-* attributes to data-bs-*
<div class="bd-example">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li
        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
        data-bs-slide-to="0"
        class="active"
      ></li>
      <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img
          src="https://abeltasmanmuseum.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/Foto-Borg-Rikkerda.jpeg"
          class="d-block w-100"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img
          src="https://abeltasmanmuseum.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/1.jpg"
          class="d-block w-100"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img
          src="https://abeltasmanmuseum.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/1.jpg"
          class="d-block w-100"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a
      class="carousel-control-prev"
      href="#carouselExampleCaptions"
      role="button"
      data-bs-slide="prev"
    >
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a
      class="carousel-control-next"
      href="#carouselExampleCaptions"
      role="button"
      data-bs-slide="next"
    >
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

Demo @ StackBlitz

OMG, that actually works! Thanks a lot! Only the "Previous" and "Next" buttons are not working though. ANy idea what could cause this?

Sorry, ya I notice that the Previous & Next buttons are using data-slide attribute. Should also replace with data-bs-slide. Check out my demo again. Thanks
